# Swift Firebase store string of username into var

Tags: swift, firebase, swift2

I am new to firebase and I have successfully logged a user in and determined whether or not he or she is online at a given time. I am creating a chat and I want it to say sent by "bob" instead of the long string. I have stored the nickname I just do not know how to get to it.

here is how i store it

```
firebase.childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(fUID).setValue(["isOnline": true, "name": username])
```

I want to store into

```
 var nickname = ""
```

the "name" value as a string

Thank you

Comment: I'm thinking it has to do with observeevent, but I cant seem to get that to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up an observer for that reference. Try this.

```
let rootRef = Firebase(url: "https://YOUR-APP.firebaseio.com")

var nickname = ""

let userRef = rootRef.childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(fUID).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    for user in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot]{
       nickname = user.value["user"] as! String
    }
})
```